# Handling A Search With No Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, search

There is a great pattern for handling searches with few or no results due to a user having constrained the search with too many filters. It involves showing all the components of a search query with the numbers of hits for that component alone, or for each combination of components.

For example, if I was searching a database of music and I built my search query from the following criteria:

1. Producer - Martin Hannett
2. Genre - Electronica
3. Year - 1977

I would get get no matches as the three don't coincide. However removing a component does allow for matches.

So rather than just displaying 'No Results', a much better handing of this situation would be to present the number of hits for each component of the the query:

Martin Hannett | <strike>Electronica</strike>  | 1975 **(2 Results)**

<strike>Martin Hannett</strike> | Electronica  | 1975 **(33 Results)**

**Given that a search term might have multiple components, how would this be done efficiently in terms of queries?** To get numbers for each component, separate queries would need to be performed for each, meaning the queries would be inefficient? I'm using Rails with Postres and PGSearch, but I think this question is much more general.

Comment: In a fulltext search engine you might do this with facets/facetted search. I don't know if postgres supports them.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of a key value store such as [Redis](http://redis.io/) in front of your PostgreSQL database to return the count of search results from Redis. Redis is optimized for fast random read/writes.
Ryan Bates did an episode on [autocomplete search](http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms) to prevent multiple queries to the main database. This case is similar.

Comment: Thanks.Sometimes I feel like like every other answer is a link to a Railscast episode (not a criticism, but a complement to Ryan Bates).